# Welcome email with create password link in laravel7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm creating an one form where the admin register the new users and then an email is sent to this new user with a welcome message and a link to create a new password.

This last part I'm having problems as I can't find info on how to generate the token and the link.

This link should redirect the user to a create password page, which is different than the reset password.

Thanks !

Below is my add user controller:

```
public function contactSave(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $request->_token;

        $user= new User;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;     
        $user->password = $password;
        $user->save();


        if($user->id)
        {
            $CustomerContact= new CustomerContact;

            // $CustomerContact->name = $request->name;
            // $CustomerContact->email = $request->email;
            $CustomerContact->phone = $request->phone;
            $CustomerContact->address = $request->address;
            $CustomerContact->user_id = $user->id;
            $CustomerContact->country_id = $request->country;
            $CustomerContact->state_id = $request->state;
            $CustomerContact->comment = $request->comment;
            $CustomerContact->organization = $request->organization;
            $CustomerContact->captcha = $request->captcha;

            $CustomerContact->save();

    $details = [
                'title' => 'Hi '.$request->name.'',
                'body' => 'Your account has been created successfully. Request you set your password with this link',
                // 'link' => URL::route('password/reset/'.$token)
            ];
           
            \Mail::to($request->email)->send(new \App\Mail\ContactMail($details));
          }
        return redirect('contacts')->with('success', 'User created successfully.');

        
    }
```

Current I am just sending mail to user mail id. I am not getting how to send password reset (password set link) url into that mail.
On that link click forgeot password form open and user can reset there passowrd.
Anyone idea then let me know.

Comment: Probably you can just modify the default confirm mail and route instead doing confirm it can confirm and prompt for password?

Comment: @Svetoslav Can u just guide me. I am new in this laravel. I am not exact idea how to do this?

Comment: must be password as  such ```$password=Hash::make($password); ``` are you sure?

Comment: @dılo sürücü I am doing password hash function . But my issue is different .  When user created i want to send password reset link.

Comment: u can make with observer class...

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.larashout.com/how-to-use-laravel-model-observers/amp

Comment: @dılo sürücü, How its exact work. Actually I am new in laravel. How we exact use

Comment: Actually i want send mail with default password reset functionality. I need add default password link. In that i need to create link with token also. I am not getting that point